# How can I check via macro whether the GNU libstdc++ is used?

Tags: c++, stl

How can I check via macro whether the (GNU GCC) libstdc++ STL implementation is used? Is that possible? I would like to have that working in both GCC and Clang.

For C++11 on Linux, it's probably anyway the only choice (or is it?). (STLport doesn't have C++11 support, AFAIK.) On MacOSX, (LLVM) libc++ STL is more likely, if you use Clang (maybe also for GCC, not sure).

Comment: Try `#ifdef __GLIBCXX__` after including some header.

Comment: Why? If you're using functionality of the C++ standard library, it should be *standard*, not implementation-dependent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check for `__GLIBCXX__` (or `__GLIBCPP__`, for releases before 3.4.0) macro existence, after including one of the C++ standard include files (`cstddef` is a good choice):

```
#include <cstddef>
#if defined(__GLIBCXX__) || defined(__GLIBCPP__)
  /* Using GNU GCC libstdc++, so using also its STL implementation */ 
#endif
```

Read more here:

- https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_macros.html
- https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html
- https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.1/cpp/If.html

Comment: But I guess I need to define *something* from STL first? Or does the compiler set this macro? What would be a good small include to get that macro?

Comment: @Albert Yes, you need to include some library header before checking for the macro. `__GLIBCXX__` macro is defined when you `#include <bits/c++config.h>`, but it is implementation-dependent, so it could give a syntax error under a different implementation. Ordering the different C++ library include files by size, and excluding the ones available only in newer C++ versions, I'd go with `#include <string>`. (Updating answer to reflect this)

Comment: @Albert Better yet: `#include <cstddef>`.  (Updating answer to reflect this)

Comment: I think saying "so using also its STL implementation" is almost meaningless. What the OP wants is to see which C++ Standard Library implementation is being used, and so simply saying "Using GNU GCC libstdc++" is fine. Referring to an "STL implementation" is unhelpful as it implies you're talking about something separate to the standard library, as though it's realistic to use GCC + libstdc++ + SGI STL or some other combination. When you mean the standard library say the standard library, not the "STL".

Comment: @JonathanWakely I fully agree with you. Anyway I put that comment about STL there because the OP repeatedly referred to STL in his question and tagged it with #stl.