# `__gnu_cxx::temporary_buffer` in libc++?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, libc++

My code for (GNU GCC) libstdc++ STL:

```
#include <ext/memory>
using __gnu_cxx::temporary_buffer;
```

Is there an equivalent in (LLVM) libc++? Where?

(A related question then would be, [how do I check for libstdc++/libc++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25891868/how-can-i-check-via-macro-whether-the-gnu-libstdc-is-used)?)

Comment: Maybe if you show what you are using it for?

Comment: I would suggest avoiding that extension, and avoiding `std::get_temporary_buffer()`, just use a `std::vector` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libc++ does not implement many of the libstdc++ library extensions, and also not `temporary_buffer`.

The only files that are present in `ext/` are `hash_map` and `hash_set` (well, and `__hash`)

Comment: So, can I interpret your answer as "no, there is no equivalent, use something else like `std::vector`"? Or are you saying something different?